# exclude specific lines from replacement in sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I want to delete some punctuation marks except specific lines.
Like, I want to `sed` just remove these `, : { } [ ]` marks, but not at lines 1, 4-7, 38, 39. How can I achive that?

Comment: To help community help you and to make your question clearer, post samples of your input and desired output. In addition to what you already has done and the problem with your code.

Answer (score 3):

You could add one block after another you want to exclude from your substitution:

```
sed -e '1!{ 4,7!{ 38,39! s/[][,:{}]//g ;}' -e '}' file_in > file_out
```

Example (with different ranges to keep it short):

```
$ printf 'line %s , : { } [ ]\n' {1..10} | sed -e '1!{ 4,6!{ 8,9! s/[][,:{}]//g ;}' -e '}'
line 1 , : { } [ ]
line 2
line 3
line 4 , : { } [ ]
line 5 , : { } [ ]
line 6 , : { } [ ]
line 7
line 8 , : { } [ ]
line 9 , : { } [ ]
line 10
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use the `b` command on the lines you want to preserve first:

```
sed -e 1b -e 4,7b -e 38,39b -e 's/[][,:{}]//g'
```

Or:

```
sed '
  1     b
  4,7   b
  38,39 b
  s/[][,:{}]//g'
```

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can also write it:

```
sed '1b;4,7b;38,39b;s/[][,:{}]//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl, we can use the line ranges to deselect via the very low precedence or operator.

```
$ perl -pe '1..1 or 4..7 or 38..39 or tr/][,:}{//d'
```

Another way:

```
perl -pe 'grep { $. == $_ } (1, 4..7, 38..39) or tr/[]{},://d'
```

Comment: I don't know much `perl` but, is that necessarily to write `1..1` instead of just `1` there?

Comment: @afshin The solitary 1 will not work here  bcoz it will short circuit the entire boolean condition. What we have here is the range operator `..` and which needs two operands. Alternatively, we can use `$. == 1` in place of the `1..1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that with awk

```
awk '{ if (NR !~ /^(1|[4-7]|38|39)$/) { gsub(/[,:\{\}\[\]]+/,"",$0) }; print }' your-file.txt
```

if NR (line number does not match 1 or 4 to 7 or 38 or 39, then replace signs with "nothing". Then print line

Comment: a golfed version would be `awk -F"[][,:}{]" 'NR !~ /^(1|[4-7]|3(8|9))$/{$1=$1}1' infile`

Comment: like it but I don't understand how this works. Could you please explain this $1=$1 ?

Comment: In awk, with `-F` option we can specify what delimiter to use as field seperator which default for awk is whitespaces (Tab and/or Space), so for example with `-F,` we tells awk field seperator is `, ` comma. this option also supports multiple seperators to define that's why default is _Tab_ and _Space_, and that's we should define those in brackets like `-F"[...]"`, so now you got what `-F"[][,:}{]"` is doing, right? <...>

Comment: <...> with `$1=$1` we set $1 value to itself (that we can also do $2=$2, or $3=$3, or ...) and that cause no changes in field's value of course but awk do re-evaluation of $0 based on OFS which we didn't set that, so it will cause to remove all those delimiters from the line without **O**utput **F**ield **S**eperator; and that 1 at the end is an awk idiom to print the line, same as `{ $1=$1; print }`

Comment: Yep, just found out this trick :-) pretty fun, like it! Thanks